# Material UI buttongroup not grouping inner buttons

Tags: html, reactjs, radio-button, material-ui

Currently i am working on a review score list. I have created a list with a RadioGroup and RadioButtons. 
My problem is that i have created a ListItem and now they fall apart from the RadioGroup.

My goal is to get the radiobuttons in the radiogroup with the similiar styling as in the picture.

How it looks like:

[image]

Thank you all and have a great weekend!!

The code:

```js
<List>
  <ListItem>
    <RadioGroup aria-label="Score" name="score" className={classes.groupFlex} value={`${stars}`} onChange={this.handleStars}>


      <ListItem>
        <Radio value={5} classes={{root: classes.root, checked: classes.checked}}/>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
      </ListItem>

      <ListItem>
        <Radio value={4} classes={{root: classes.root, checked: classes.checked}}/>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
      </ListItem>

      <ListItem>
        <Radio value={3} classes={{root: classes.root, checked: classes.checked}}/>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
      </ListItem>

      <ListItem>
        <Radio value={2} classes={{root: classes.root, checked: classes.checked}}/>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
      </ListItem>

      <ListItem>
        <Radio value={1} classes={{root: classes.root, checked: classes.checked}}/>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <StarIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
          <StarHalfIcon/>
        </ListItemIcon>
      </ListItem>


    </RadioGroup>
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

Comment: Can you create this as a codesandbox so we can see how it is behaving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it..

By default the radiogroup will assign if the Radio is checked or not.
But because my Radio is not directly inside of the Radiogroup it won't assign the new value to the Radio component.

I've added the checked parameter and edited the Radio by:

```js
<Radio value={5} classes={{root: classes.root, checked: classes.checked}}  checked={this.props.stars === 5} />
```